# Making plugins in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm looking for a good tutorial about making plugins for rails. Something about ActiveRecords extending with good example app. Have you seen one?

Thank you.

UPD: The one on the guides.rubyonrails.org is rather obscure like for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jeffmdean.com/2008/5/30/tutorial-creating-plugins-in-rails it's look good for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [Redmine Plugin Tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial) is about making a Redmine plugin but plugins are such an important part of Redmine that you may find it useful generally.